# I want to replace specific values from one column to another column to Nan Values?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

```
Address                                                Locality

Aaya Nagar, New Delhi                                    NaN
84, Near Honda Showroom, Adchini, New Delhi              NaN
15/16/16-A, Plot 9-D, Aditya Mega Mall                   NaN
31-BC, Ground Floor, Aditya Mega Mall                    NaN
```

Now i want to replace Aaya Nagar in NaN, adchini in NaN, Aditya Mega Mall in NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by:

```
df['Locality'] = df['Address'].str.split(',').str[2]
```

Comment: Sorry I posted partial doubt, please do let me know with the above one which i have rectified now.